# Help me understand the meaning of a phrase I use regularly- "just ducky"

Tags: meaning, etymology

When people ask me; "how are you"? I love to answer with "just ducky" (sp?) and it usually gets a disarming smile and sets a light-hearted tone for conversation to follow. I adopted it as part of my personal argot when I was a kid watching the classic 70's sitcom *Night* *Court*. (Moose always used to say it).

I believe it's a British phrase but unfortunately, if the person happens to ask me what it means, I can only admit That I don't know. I'm pretty sure it is a sarcastic way of saying "fine" (e.g.; F.I.N.E.)but really wish I knew for sure and how the phrase came into the fringe if the English language.

Does anyone have a definitive answer?

I'd be happy as a pig in a poke if you do.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161975/why-do-the-words-ducky-and-jake-mean-fine-or-satisfactory

Comment: [Pig in a poke](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/a-pig-in-a-poke.html).

Answer (score 1):

In British English *ducky* is used [similar to "dear" or "darling"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ducky) as a pet name for another person. In North American English, it is used to say that something is charming or delightful. So to say you are "just ducky" would mean you are delighted.

The Oxford Dictionary is not specific about the origin. It seems the North American version comes from the British version, which is from the 14th century and has its origin in the word "duck" as it refers to the animal.